# SEO Practice for Multilanguage Website only with Cookies

Tags: php, html, cookies, seo

I almost finish my website project and I'm just translating the labels for English and Portuguese words.
The user will have the possibility to change the language of the website by clicking a link. That link will only change a cookie stored **and not redirect** to other pages (subdomains, etc).

What I'm asking is, in this situation, what best practices can I implement in my project in order to fill good practices of SEO?

I will probably change the HTML tag to the chosen language `<html lang='en'>` or `<html lang='pt'>`, plus I will change the meta tags like `description` and `title`. Is this a good practice or should I stick with only one language in this tags no matter what language is selected?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about SEO

Comment: You should follow [Google's advice for multilingual websites](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2010/03/working-with-multi-regional-websites.html)

Comment: This is the perfect question for [Webmasters Stack Exchange](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com), though :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Googlebot does not use cookies, hence will only be able to see the "default" version of your website. It is **absolutely necessary** to provide a unique URL for every piece of translated content that you offer.

There are three established ways to do this:

1. TLD

   - en: http://www.example.com/article-1.html
   - de: http://www.example.de/article-1.html
2. Subdomain

   - en: http://en.example.com/article-1.html
   - de: http://de.example.com/article-1.html
3. Subfolder

   - en: http://www.example.com/en/article-1.html
   - de: http://www.example.com/de/article-1.html

Altough there might be slight preferences towards the TLD version, chose whatever fit's your IT best. You can assign a geographical region for a subfolder/subdomain later on in the Google Webmaster Tools.

Please consult the [Internationalization Guidelines of Google](https://support.google.com/webmasters/topic/2370587?hl=en&ref_topic=2371375) for a more in depth description.

PS: I feel I need to stress this even more: **Do not use parameters or cookies when delivering multilingual content!** :)